# Copy the background color from another column

Tags: excel, vba

In column A1:A145 need code to highlight color.
Apply format color in A1, how many rows? Base on the image1.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3QVC.png)

In column A ,  14 rows will have yellow, next 14 rows will have blue and so on. (number will always change)
In column B need to repeat the number that appear in column D.

Looking for this result image 2
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEB4J.png)

The below code only copy the color and number from column C at the end of row A:145, what we need is  trying to highlight rows base on another cell value, working with sheet 1 until sheet 8 or more sheets.

```
Sub Color_My_Cells()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long
Dim Lastrow As Long
Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Dim Lastrowa As Long
Lastrowa = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To Lastrowa
Cells(Lastrow, 1).Resize(Cells(i, 2).Value) = Cells(i, 2).Value
Cells(Lastrow, 1).Resize(Cells(i, 2)).Interior.Color = Cells(i, 2).Interior.Color
Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Why is the code referring to column `B` when the data is on column `C`?

Comment: Because I modified the excel file columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@GoalExcel the code below loops through all sheets in your Excel file and repeat the same steps for each one.

```
Sub ColorMyCells()
    
    Dim i, j, intRowCounterAB, intRowC As Integer
    
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        ws.Activate
        
        intRowC = Evaluate("=COUNTA(C:C)")
        intRowCounterAB = 1
    
        For i = 1 To intRowC
            For j = 0 To Range("C" & i).Value - 1
                Range("A" & intRowCounterAB).Interior.Color = Range("C" & i).Interior.Color
                Range("B" & intRowCounterAB).Value = Range("D" & i).Value
                intRowCounterAB = intRowCounterAB + 1
            Next j
        Next i
    Next ws
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @ricardogerbaudo, works perfect!!. What about for many sheets, see above comments, sheet1 until sheet 8, or less always change, how to run code in this way.

Comment: @GoalExcel I edited the original code to include another loop that goes through all existing sheets in your Excel file (the workbook).